# installing java ee 7 on a brand new mac book air

Tags: macos, environment-variables, java-ee-7

I managed to install JDK 7 thanks to it being a dmg file, but I'm having problems installing Java EE 7... I have registered JAVA_HOME on launchd.conf but its still not finding it... here's the error:

```
sudo sh ./java_ee_sdk-7-unix.sh 
Extracting the installer archive...
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:139)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:961)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:877)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:263)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
Extracting the installer runtime...
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
Extracting the installer resources...
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
Extracting the installer metadata...
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:139)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:961)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:877)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:263)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
chmod: product-installer.sh: No such file or directory
sh: product-installer.sh: No such file or directory
```

and here's what happens when i echo JAVA_HOME:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

Any help? I'm kinda new to mac

Comment: At first sight I'd say your downloaded distribution archive was damaged, can you compare the size on disk with the announced size on the website?

Comment: you're referring to the sh file?

Comment: Read the error messages more carefully. The first error is "java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" - your download is corrupt.

Comment: ok ill try redownloading

Comment: Especially if you are new to your platform, you might prefer to download Netbeans from https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html , its installer (for Mac it comes as a dmg file) will also set up a GF4 server for you.  That server can be used from Netbeans, but also from other IDE's.

Comment: I got it working, it was definitely a corrupt download. I already have Intellij Idea though, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Good that is was so simple to solve :)

Comment: if you can put it as an answer i can accept it, so please do